# Using map on data from graphql

Tags: typescript, next.js, graphql, strapi

I have a nextjs app using typescript and a Strapi backend with graphql

I'm trying to simple get the graphql from strapi and display it in the react app.

I'm trying to display a list of font names.

In react I have this query, this works in the playground

```
import { gql } from "@/node_modules/@apollo/client/core/index";

export const FONT_DATA = gql`
    query font_data{
        fonts{
            data{
                attributes{
                    font_name
                }
        }
    }
}
`
```

I'm generating types using codegen.

```
export type Font = {
  __typename?: 'Font';
  createdAt?: Maybe<Scalars['DateTime']['output']>;
  font_name?: Maybe<Scalars['String']['output']>;
  publishedAt?: Maybe<Scalars['DateTime']['output']>;
  updatedAt?: Maybe<Scalars['DateTime']['output']>;
};

export type FontEntity = {
  __typename?: 'FontEntity';
  attributes?: Maybe<Font>;
  id?: Maybe<Scalars['ID']['output']>;
};

export type FontEntityResponse = {
  __typename?: 'FontEntityResponse';
  data?: Maybe<FontEntity>;
};

export type FontEntityResponseCollection = {
  __typename?: 'FontEntityResponseCollection';
  data: Array<FontEntity>;
  meta: ResponseCollectionMeta;
};

export type FontFiltersInput = {
  and?: InputMaybe<Array<InputMaybe<FontFiltersInput>>>;
  createdAt?: InputMaybe<DateTimeFilterInput>;
  font_name?: InputMaybe<StringFilterInput>;
  id?: InputMaybe<IdFilterInput>;
  not?: InputMaybe<FontFiltersInput>;
  or?: InputMaybe<Array<InputMaybe<FontFiltersInput>>>;
  publishedAt?: InputMaybe<DateTimeFilterInput>;
  updatedAt?: InputMaybe<DateTimeFilterInput>;
};

export type FontInput = {
  font_name?: InputMaybe<Scalars['String']['input']>;
  publishedAt?: InputMaybe<Scalars['DateTime']['input']>;
};
```

In react I have a simple page where I am calling the query and trying to display the font names

```
'use client'
import { getDataFromTree } from '@apollo/client/react/ssr'
import withApollo from '../lib/withApollo'
import { FontEntity,  FontEntityResponse,  FontEntityResponseCollection} from '@/generated'
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client'
import { FONT_DATA } from '@/graphql/queries'

const Home = () => {
  // const data: FontEntityResponse  = useThemeContext()?.data;

  const {data, loading} = useQuery<FontEntityResponse, FontEntity>(FONT_DATA)

  if(loading || !data) return <div>Loading</div>

  console.log(Array.isArray(data))

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {data?.data?.attributes?.map((font:FontEntity) => (
          <li key={font.id}>{font?.font_name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withApollo(Home, { getDataFromTree });
```

The map errors with `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Font'` which is because its not an array.

The console.log also says its not an array.

The graphql returns an object but how do I use that with the map, or am I using the wrong type.

Update

if I do `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))`

I get

```
{
  "fonts": {
    "__typename": "FontEntityResponseCollection",
    "data": [
      {
        "__typename": "FontEntity",
        "attributes": {
          "__typename": "Font",
          "font_name": "Black"
        }
      },
      {
        "__typename": "FontEntity",
        "attributes": {
          "__typename": "Font",
          "font_name": "Jasper"
        }
      },
      {
        "__typename": "FontEntity",
        "attributes": {
          "__typename": "Font",
          "font_name": "Varly"
        }
      },
      {
        "__typename": "FontEntity",
        "attributes": {
          "__typename": "Font",
          "font_name": "Brother"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works with strapi, but usually graphql response looks like this:

```
data.nameOfYourResolver.arrayObjectOrOtherTypeOfData
```

Your types are all wrong.
In your case, it should look something like this:

```
export type FontEntityResponse = {
  fonts: Maybe<FontEntityData>; //object
};

export type FontEntityData = {
  data: Maybe<FontEntity[]> //Array
};

export type FontEntity = {
  attributes: Maybe<Font>; //Object

export type Font = {
  fontName: Maybe<string>; //string



data.fonts.data(attribute => {
   console.log(attribute.font_name)
//...
})
```

Again, I don't know what type of data is it exactly, but your property names are wrongly named

All you need to do is check for the types of these properties

```
fonts{
       data{
            attributes{
               font_name }}}
```

You can `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` to see all the data inside

Also, I think that  in
`const {data, loading} = useQuery<FontEntityResponse, FontEntity>(FONT_DATA)`

FontEntity should supposed to be used for variable types that are used when fetching this resolver.

Comment: these are the type generated with codegen, I haven't created them

Comment: I have updated the question with the console log you suggested

Comment: Well it looks like it generated the wrong types. I updated my answer. Maybe they are outdated or something, but based on the console.log you provided, it is ```data.fonts.data.map```

Comment: These types are from the Graphql Code Generator - https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen